# nested div - 100% width nested in fixed width container

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can i get `div B` to have a width of 100% while nested in `Div A` which has a fixed width?
[image]

```
.divA{width:600px; margin:0 auto;}
.divB{width:100%; height:20px;  background-color:black}

.filler{height:800px; background-color:grey}
```

```
<div class='divA'>
 <div class='filler'></div>
 <div class='divB'></div>
</div>
```

**edit** the problem was: `.divA` had a `position:relative` i had to take out

Comment: Actually, this should work. Why isn't it working here?

Comment: @PraveenKumar div b couldnt get 100%

Comment: @tq Didn't read the question. I thought the image was an error. Actually to achieve that, yes, as others said, you need to use `position`ing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
.divB {
    width:100%;
    height:20px;
    min-width:600px;
    background-color:black;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;

 }
```

[FullScren view](http://jsfiddle.net/x4XKm/embedded/result/)

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/x4XKm/)

Comment: Any idea how to do it with `position: relative` on `divA`?  I want `divB`'s width to be preserved, but I also want to horizontally center `divB` relative to `divA`, which I can do with jQuery, but I believe I need the `position: relative` to do it.

Answer (score 2):

```
.divA {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}.divB {
    width: 100 % ;
    height: 20px;
    background - color: black;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0
}

.filler {
    height: 800px;
    background - color: grey
}
```

You can just set `position:absolute` and `left:0`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eVprt/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
.divA { width: 600px;    margin: 0 auto;}

.divB { width: 100 % ; height: 20px; background-color: black; position: absolute; left: 0;
}  

.filler {    height: 800px; background-color: grey;   }
```