# 100% Screen width on div nested in fixed width div css

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to get a nested div to be full width on screen out of the div that it's contained/nested in.

http://jsfiddle.net/TheeAndre/JAdps/

```
<div class="fixedwidth">
    <div class="fullwidth"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14743905/nested-div-100-width-nested-in-fixed-width-container?rq=1

Answer (score 20):

Try

```
width:100vw;
```

instead of

```
width:100%;
```

Check for compatibility issues: http://caniuse.com/#search=vw

Pascalz, yes in your jsfiddle it works, but only as long as you don't specify a position other than static for your parent. In many cases you need your parent to be position:relative, so the child will relate width:100% to parent width.

Comment: `vw` and `vh` go crazy in mobile

Answer (score 3):

try this :

```
.fullwidth {
    background-color:#000; 
    width:100%; 
    height:100px; 
    position:absolute; 
    z-index:999;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: humm not for me, [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pascalz/Muspa/), I see the back div on the red one